# problem to get back to the position which is clicked in android studio

Tags: java, android, camera

**small description(problem facing)**

here  is the postlist activity,what i want is that when user clicks the (any post) i want to show the detail activity of that post and want user to move back to the same post position when clicks back button . But the problem i am facing is that user is not able come to correct post position after moving back from the detail activity insteed of that it takes user to the begining of the post. 
so, below is the code ...what i think is that it is because of onStart() function calling... if somebody helps me with this situation it will be vary helpfull...

````
  protected void onStart() {
      super.onStart();

      childEventListener=(new ChildEventListener() {  
          @Override
          public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

              Blog blog = dataSnapshot.getValue(Blog.class);
              blogList.add(blog);

              Collections.reverse(blogList);

              blogRecyclerAdapter = new BlogRecyclerAdapter(PostListActivity.this, blogList);
              shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmer();
              shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

              recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              refreshLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              recyclerView.setAdapter(blogRecyclerAdapter);
              blogRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }

          @Override
          public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

              //when we want to update item then this will be use
          }

          @Override
          public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

              //when we want to remove item then this will be use

          }

          @Override
          public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
              //when we want to move item then this will be use
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
              //    when we want to cancel item then this will be use

          }
      });

      mDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
  }

@Override
  protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      shimmerFrameLayout.startShimmer();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmer();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop() {
      super.onStop();
      blogList.clear();
  }```
````